# Why do I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-extensions'" when running startapp

Tags: python, django, django-extensions

I am learning Django through the dj4e course. In my project I have set up django-extensions for a previous section of the course. When I moved to a new section and created a new app with the code

```
python manage.py startapp autos
```

I get the error

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-extensions'"

I have resolved this by commenting out 'django-extensions' in the settings.py file.

However can anyone talk me through why this happened, I'm trying to get a better understanding of the processes.

**edit** I am working in a virtual environment and django-extensions is installed in that environment.

Comment: You needed to install ``django-extensions`` package, for example, using ``pip``.

Comment: I already have it installed in my virtual environment and was working in that environment

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether `django-extensions` is installed in your virtual environment by entering below code in your shell

```
import django_extensions
django_extensions.VERSION
```

if you are getting `ModuleNotFoundError` then install `django-extensions` using `pip install django-extensions`

After successfull installation add `django_extensions` to your `settings.py` file as below.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_extensions',
)
```

Comment: I already have it installed in my virtual environment and was working in that environment. And it is in my settings.py. only way I could make it work was commenting it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to do migration after 'django_extensions' was installed:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Even if you get the message "No migrations to apply.", next time an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-extensions'" will not appear.